# import csv file into mysql using phpexcel but leading zeros are removing

Tags: mysql, csv, phpexcel

Data in my csv file looks like this.When i try to use below code the leading zeros are removing.There was no fixed length of article number.It could be any length

```
000086;Grand Trunk Schlafsack, grün;892902000086;1;34,27
000109;Grand Trunk Hängematte, grün;0892902000109;1;15,57
BD159-150-2XL;Grand Trunk Hängematte, blau;0892902000116;1;15,57
BD240-150-44;Grand Trunk Hängematte, blau;0892902000116;1;15,57
BD235-200-35/38;Grand Trunk Hängematte, blau;0892902000116;1;15,57
```

below is my code to import csv into myssql using phpexcel

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');  
try {
        $inputFileType = 'CSV';
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objReader = $objReader->setDelimiter(";");
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); 
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}
$NewArray = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
 echo '<pre>';
print_r($NewArray);
```

My out put from the above code is

```
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => 86
    [1] => 
    [2] => 892902000086
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 34,27
)
[1] => Array
(
    [0] => 109
    [1] => 
    [2] => 892902000109
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 15,57
)
[2] => Array
(
    [0] => BD159-150-2XL
    [1] => 
    [2] => 892902000116
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 15,57
)
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => BD240-150-44
        [1] => 
        [2] => 892902000116
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 15,57
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => BD235-200-35/38
        [1] => 
        [2] => 892902000116
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 15,57
    )
Here in array[0] leading zeros are removed .But I need same values as in csv like 
000086
000109
BD159-150-2XL
BD240-150-44
BD235-200-35/38

How can i achieve this? Threre is no fixed length of article number. It could be 6characters/10 charactes / 3 characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: I think your .csv data should be quoted to be interpreted as is (as text, string...). Can't you just include them? A regexp/replace like this should do the trick (as long as your file ends with a blank line): regex `([^;\n]*)([;\n])` replace `"$1"$2`. Maybe PHPExcel could be configured to read all data as text, even without quotes, but I don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it is automatically converting it to a number, try to run a simple loop to convert it back to a string

```
foreach ($NewArray as &$row) {
    $row[0]= sprintf("%06d", $row[0]);
}
```

Comment: But in place of array[0] i have 9BE200-100-L , BD240-150-44 values like this.But there is no fixed length. In this case it fails to insert into db. I am getting six zeros in that place. Edited my question.